# How to add CSS code within if...else if...else Javascript statement

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an if...else if...else statement in Javascript that will change the style of a specific CSS ID based on a specific number. The if...else if...else code isn't the problem, it's just that as a Javascript novice (putting it lightly...) I'm not sure where to add the CSS code to execute it. From what I understand I would put it in the areas I designated as "CSS CODE" below (sorry for the poorly formated code).

```
if (Number == 9) {CSS CODE} else if (Number == 8) {CSS CODE}
```

I looked at another question here and the code that was provided to achieve this is below.

```
var element = document.getElementById("ElementID");  
element.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
```

When I placed the var at the top and the element.style.etc within the CSS CODE section it did not work properly.

As a side note I need all the styling to be contained within the script, so adding a new class to it won't work. Along the same line of thought I can't use jQuery for any of this or I would have already :)

Comment: What you describe with finding the element at the top and then setting the element.style within the if clause should work.  When you say it "did not work properly" what happened?

Comment: define "did not work properly". It must work, unless you are not telling something !important.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I placed the var at the top and the element.style.etc...". Are you putting javascript code inside the css file ?

Comment: Eek, I know this is sorta pseudo-code, but `Number` is a global function/constructor and probably should not be used as a variable name.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. What I mean by "did not work properly" is that the background color does not change for the element I specified. I started testing the if...else if...else statement by making it display specific text, so I know that part is working as intended. The code Floyd Pink provided below is essentially what my code looks like. As to the use of Number as the function name, I'm actually using something different but just used that for the example.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work?

```
    var element = document.getElementById("ElementID");
    var Number = 8;
    if (Number == 9) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    } else if (Number == 8) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
```

Comment: Nope. That's how I had it set up originally.

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing in? Does it fail in all browsers or just one? Are you sure that "ElementID" is the correct ID and is unique in your document? And is Javascript enabled? Have you tried stepping through the code in Firebug? Does it throw a Javascript error? The code given looks fine as it stands, so I don't know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById("ElementID");
var Number = 1;

switch(Number)
{
case 1:
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  break;
case 2:
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
  break;
default:
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#FAB";
  break;
}
```